# Randomly select multiple values from a list based on a TRUE filter in Excel

Tags: excel, random, filter, excel-formula, office365

#### Summary

I would like to select multiple randomly selected options from a list within Excel, but filtered to only include those with a TRUE indicator in another column. The number of random selections to make will need to be vary. Additionally, duplicates shouldn't be pulled. Ideally, I would like to have the formula contained within one cell, and have it spill to the required length, if such a thing would be possible.

#### Current attempt

I have tried making this logic work through the combined used of `=INDEX`, `=RANDBETWEEN` `=FILTER` and a helper `=RAND()` column, in an attempt to filter the data, then randomly select from it. The issue I'm finding is that `=FILTER` does not like to combine properly (although I'm likely doing something wrong). Additionally, this involves copying the formula down to each cell I'd like a new randomly selected option for, which isn't ideal if possible.

#### Example of required output

| ID | T/F | Number to randomly select? | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | 5 | 2 [Formula is here and spill down] |
| 2 | TRUE |  | 5 |
| 3 | FALSE |  | 7 |
| 4 | FALSE |  | 9 |
| 5 | TRUE |  | 12 |
| 6 | FALSE |  |  |
| 7 | TRUE |  |  |
| 8 | TRUE |  |  |
| 9 | TRUE |  |  |
| 10 | FALSE |  |  |
| 11 | TRUE |  |  |
| 12 | TRUE |  |  |

Here is an example of how I'd ideally like the output of the data. The data itself is in `A1:B13`. I'd enter the number of options to randomly select in `C2`, then the output would be generated based on a solution contained in `D2`, which spills down accordingly. The requirements that it only selects from an ID population in column A where the `TRUE/FALSE` indicator from column B for that ID is `TRUE`. I'm looking for the solution to this question to be the formula I'd need to put into `D2`, please.

#### Extra detail

I'm always looking to improve, so any explanation on how something works is always appreciated, so I don't end up asking the same things again!

I am using MSO 365, but I am restricted to **version 2108** due to rollout schedules.

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: What formula you are using to get `D1` to `D5` result.

Comment: @Harun24hr - sorry, I should have clarified further. This is what I'm trying to achieve. I'll amend the question to clear that up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=LET(X,FILTER(A2:A13,B2:B13),INDEX(SORTBY(X,RANDARRAY(COUNT(X))),SEQUENCE(C2),1))
```

Or, if one needs these to be ascending:

```
=LET(X,FILTER(A2:A13,B2:B13),SORT(INDEX(SORTBY(X,RANDARRAY(COUNT(X))),SEQUENCE(C2),1)))
```

A last small edit could be to adjust the value in `C2` with a smaller number if need be (avoid errors spilled down):

```
=LET(X,FILTER(A2:A13,B2:B13),SORT(INDEX(SORTBY(X,RANDARRAY(COUNT(X))),SEQUENCE(MIN(COUNTIF(B2:B13,TRUE),C2)),1)))
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the first formula you posted, but I'm receiving a #VALUE error. Do you have any insight on why?

Comment: =LET(X,FILTER(A2:A13,B2:B13),INDEX(SORTBY(B2:B13,RANDARRAY(COUNT(A2:A13))),SEQUENCE(C2),1))